# Displaying progress of file upload in a ProgressBar with SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sftp, ssh.net

I want to show the progress of an uploading process on my `ProgressBar`, Here is the code of my button "Upload":

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Port = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    string Host = textBox1.Text;
    string Username = textBox3.Text;
    string Password = textBox4.Text;
    string WorkingDirectory = textBox6.Text;
    string UploadDirectory = textBox5.Text;

    FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(UploadDirectory);
    string UploadFile = FI.FullName;
    Console.WriteLine(FI.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("UploadFile" + UploadFile);

    var Client = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password);
    Client.Connect();
    if (Client.IsConnected)
    {
        var FS = new FileStream(UploadFile, FileMode.Open);
        if (FS != null)
        {
            Client.UploadFile(FS, WorkingDirectory + FI.Name, null);
            Client.Disconnect();
            Client.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Upload complete", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to provide a callback to the `uploadCallback` argument of `SftpClient.UploadFile`.

```
public void UploadFile(
    Stream input, string path, Action<ulong> uploadCallback = null)
```

And of course, you have to upload on a background thread or use an asynchronous upload (`SftpClient.BeginUploadFile`).

---

Example using a background thread (task):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Run Upload on background thread
    Task.Run(() => Upload());
}

private void Upload()
{
    try
    {
        int Port = 22;
        string Host = "example.com";
        string Username = "username";
        string Password = "password";
        string RemotePath = "/remote/path/";
        string SourcePath = @"C:\local\path\";
        string FileName = "upload.txt";

        using (var stream = new FileStream(SourcePath + FileName, FileMode.Open))
        using (var client = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))
        {
            client.Connect();
            // Set progress bar maximum on foreground thread
            int max = (int)stream.Length;
            progressBar1.Invoke(
                (MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Maximum = max; });
            // Upload with progress callback
            client.UploadFile(stream, RemotePath + FileName, UpdateProgresBar);
            MessageBox.Show("Upload complete");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}

private void UpdateProgresBar(ulong uploaded)
{
    // Update progress bar on foreground thread
    progressBar1.Invoke(
        (MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Value = (int)uploaded; });
}
```

[image]

---

For *download* see:
[Displaying progress of file download in a ProgressBar with SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44442714/850848)

Comment: Man, you are really awesome, it works well for me, a thousand thanks.